# Combine blur and click event

Tags: javascript, jquery, events

I try to implement the following code

```
$("#email").blur(function(){
    var email = $("#email").val();
    $.ajax({ 
        type: "POST", 
        url: "email_check.php", 
        data: "email="+email, 
        cache: false,
        success: function(msg) { 
            $("#emailcheck").ajaxComplete(function() { 
                if (msg == "OK") {
                    $(this).fadeIn("slow").html('email available');
                }
            });
        }
    }); 

    $("#register").click(function(){
        $("#emailcheck").hide();
    });


<div class="clear" id="emailline">email:<input type="text" name="email"   id="email" style="border:1px solid #928b8b;"></div>
<div id="emailcheck"></div>
<input  type="button" class="form_button" id="register" value="register!">
```

The problem is when I click the 'register' button, the word "email available" disappears, but it appears again. I want it to disappear forever. Can anyone tell me what's wrong with my code, any help will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Bless you @reporter for editing this! ;)

Answer (score 1):

The problem looks like it could be resting with a race condition between the `blur` function firing, as well as the `click` function firing order.

Think about this: if your `#email` element is in focus, nothing's happening, everything's great. When you click on the `#register` button, two things will happen: first, the `blur` function will fire, as well as the `click` function, hiding the `#emailcheck` element.

The AJAX call will almost likely complete AFTER the `click` function has hidden the `#emailcheck` element, thus showing it again after it's been hidden...make sense?

What you need to do is find a way to disable that `blur` event listening when the `click` function is called. I would be tempted to try either unbinding the event:

```
$("#register").click(function(){
    $("#email").unbind("blur");
    $("#emailcheck").hide();
});
```

...or use a boolean flag to attempt to check to see if the blur event should be fired:

```
var run_blur = true;

$("#email").blur(function(){
    if (run_blur){
        ...
    }
}

$("#register").click(function(){
    run_blur = false;
    $("#emailcheck").hide();
});
```

This assumes execution order would be favourable, but I hope this helps! Let me know if you're still struggling! :)

**EDIT:**

Here's an example on jsfiddle for the boolean flag version of what I'm talking about: [jsfiddle boolean example](http://jsfiddle.net/ykN5V/3/).

Comment: thanks for your answer, could you give me a demo on jsffidle?

Comment: No problem, updated my answer...hope it's the answer you're looking for! :)

Answer (score 0):

Use,

```
success: function(msg) {  
            $("#emailcheck").ajaxComplete(function() {  
                if (msg == "OK") { 
                    $(this).fadeIn("slow").html('email available'); 
                    hideDiv();
                } 
            });



function hideDiv(){
    $("#register").click(function(){ 
            $("#emailcheck").html('');
            $("#emailcheck").hide(); 
        }); 
}
```

Comment: This might not solve the problem of an asynchronous AJAX request showing the `#emailcheck` div on a successful request.

Comment: I'm not sure I completely understand what you're trying to do here. Why are you attempting to bind the `click` event after every successful AJAX call?